# C++ Program menu using do while and switch

Tags: c++

I am able to display the program menu to the user, but I can't get the actual math to execute. For example, when I enter 2 it only displays 0, instead of letting me enter two integers and then either multiplying them or adding them. How can I get it to allow the user to enter options for 1, 2, or 3, and then have it do what they entered?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int choice;
    int numberOne = 0;
    int numberTwo = 0;
    int sumOfTwoNumbers = 0;
    int productOfTwoNumbers = 0;

    do{
        cout <<"Please select one of the following options:  \n";

        cout << "1: Enter two integer values\n"
        "2: Add the two values\n"
        "3: Multiply the two values\n"
        "4: Exit\n";

        cout << "Enter your selection (1, 2,3 or 4): ";
        std::cin >> choice;

            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Enter two integer values. " << endl;
                cin >> numberOne >> numberTwo;
                break;

            case 2:
                sumOfTwoNumbers = numberOne + numberTwo;
                cout << sumOfTwoNumbers << endl;
                break;

            case 3:
                productOfTwoNumbers = numberOne * numberTwo;
                cout << productOfTwoNumbers << endl;
                break;

            case 4:
                cout << "You have chosen Exit, Goodbye.";
                break;

            default:
                cout<< "Your selection must be between 1 and 4!\n";
                break;

          }

    }while(choice!= '4');

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only ask for the two numbers in case 1. In the other options the numbers are left as their default value of `0`. You need to make sure that you assign the two numbers no matter which option is chosen. Also your cases don't make much sense as all of the options require inputting two numbers. I remove case 1 and simply move the lines

```
cout << "Enter two integer values. " << endl;
cin >> numberOne >> numberTwo;
```

Above the `switch` statement:

```
cout <<"Please select one of the following options:  \n";

cout << 
"1: Add the two values\n"
"2: Multiply the two values\n"
"3: Exit\n";

cout << "Enter your selection (1, 2, or 3): ";
std::cin >> choice;
cout << "Enter two integer values. " << endl;
cin >> numberOne >> numberTwo;
switch (choice)
{
   case 1:
      sumOfTwoNumbers = numberOne + numberTwo;
      cout << sumOfTwoNumbers << endl;
      break;
   case 2:
      //etc
```